# Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL

Tags: netbeans, web, tomcat, servidor

primero dar las gracias y ver si alguna persona le sucedió lo mismo, cabe mencionar que uso netbeans portable 8.1 con tomcat 7.0.92: el error es el siguiente.

> Starting Tomcat process... Waiting for Tomcat... Tomcat server
>   started. In-place deployment at D:\Proyectos Web\SIGED\build\web
>   Deployment is in progress...
>   deploy?config=file%3A%2FD%3A%2FUsuarios%2FPRAC-J%7E1%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext7318633045463520082.xml&path=/SIGED
>   Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:
>   http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?config=file%3A%2FD%3A%2FUsuarios%2FPRAC-J%7E1%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext7318633045463520082.xml&path=/SIGED
>   D:\Proyectos Web\SIGED\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1048: The module has
>   not been deployed. See the server log for details. BUILD FAILED (total
>   time: 47 seconds)

Estuve investigando sobre este error y encontré una repuesta que al principio me pareció rara, el compañero explicaba que "solo le corría el tomcat, cuando quitaba el cable de Internet, después lo volvía a colocar" esto lo hacia cada vez que no levantaba el servidor web (tomcat) con el netbeans. Y efectivamente es lo que me viene sucediendo. Resalto que en la computadora donde monte todo esto, no poseo permisos de administrador(Ordenador de trabajo). Lo probé en mi hogar y funciona a la perfección.

Comment: Hola. ¿usas un proxy en tu trabajo?

Comment: Así es. es algo como abcde.peru y luego esta la salida a Internet.

Comment: ¿En la Configuración de red de Area Local-> Opciones de Internet -> Propiedades de Internet -> Configuración LAN -> Opciones Avanzadas -> Excepciones tienes colocada en la lista los 127.0.0.1 y localhost?

Comment: no compañero, no se encuentra 127.0.0.1 y localhost en la lista.

Comment: Los acabo de añadir. Y levanto sin problemas, Gracias eres un capo. Para finalizar no abría problemas de seguridad si añado esas direcciones verdad?

Comment: Voy a colocar el mismo comentario a manera de respuesta para que si pasa cualquier otra persona por aquí con el mismo problema vea que el problema tiene solución y como aplicarlo. Te pido me apoyes con tu palomita de respuesta aceptada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para este caso en particular en el que se esta usando un proxy para salir a internet

Es necesario ir a la Configuración de red de Area Local-> Opciones de Internet -> Propiedades de Internet -> Configuración LAN -> Opciones Avanzadas -> Excepciones

Y colocar ademas de lo allí existente: 127.0.0.1 y localhost.